# Write Word Doc On The Fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, http-headers

I've got this bit of code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Bio.docx");
Response.BinaryWrite(lawyerBio.MakeDoc());
```

It works just fine in all major browsers, but is failing in IE8.

What IE8 is doing is the first time I hit the page, it gives a popup error that says:

> Internet Explorer cannot download 'John-Smith' from 'site domain'.
>
> Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The
>   requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try
>   again later.

If I hit OK, and then refresh the page, it downloads the file just fine, with the filename Bio.docx. It fails the first time, everytime and it works the second time, every time. John-Smith is the filename of the page this is taking place on, so it appears as if the first time through, it's not picking up on the content-disposition.

Are there any known issues with IE8, or anything you guys can see that I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

---

**Update**

Below are the headers sent with this file:

```
        Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
    [2] => Pragma: no-cache
    [3] => Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    [4] => Expires: -1
    [5] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    [6] => Set-Cookie: website#sc_wede=1; path=/
    [7] => Set-Cookie: website#lang=en; path=/
    [8] => Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zabhwz55brq0ebfyjqn1c3bm; path=/; HttpOnly
    [9] => Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Bio.docx
    [10] => X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
    [11] => Set-Cookie: SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=323F079A90B545F39F8A6A9EB9B919DB; expires=Fri, 26-Oct-2012 17:44:57 GMT; path=/
    [12] => Set-Cookie: SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=118B88825A054BA1BAF327B0561C3EBB,1; path=/
    [13] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    [14] => Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2011 17:44:57 GMT
    [15] => Connection: close
    [16] => Content-Length: 169581
)
```

Comment: You'll notice IE8 isn't lumped in with "All major browsers" ;)

Comment: Are you using SSL or Cache-Control headers?

Comment: No SSL, but I will grab a copy of the headers from FF Web Dev and attach them to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the Cache-Control headers. See [MSKB #323308](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=323308). Despite its title, I have found a number of posts online that suggest that not caching downloading files might cause non-SSL websites to fail in Internet Explorer as well. I would try adding the registry value `BypassHTTPNoCacheCheck` that the KB article suggests - if it works then, you will need to remove the caching headers from your response.

Comment: I think you're right, but there's no way I'm going to convince my client to mess with their registry on a production webserver. Any idea how to turn it off through code?

Comment: According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#99190, removing the Cache-Control and Pragma headers should do the trick.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, because this is WHY it's failing. HOW to fix it is much more complicated, but I have a feeling is a mash of things between IIS, C# and SiteCore - but that's specific to my solution and not to the problem, which is what other people are going to search for and find this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (instead of `BinaryWrite`)...(you can always swap `MemoryStream` for `FileStream` if the files is not directly on disk).

```
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (Stream s = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int bytes;
                while ((bytes = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                }
            }
            Response.Flush();
```

Comment: I tried running this with MemoryStream(), but still had the same results.

Comment: Try changing the name of the document with each call to see if it's a caching issue. Instead of bio.docx make it `Guid.NewGuid() + ".docx"`

Comment: I've got this implemented, IE8 still sees it as john-smith on the first run, then guid.docx on subsequent ones.

Comment: Can you share the URL you are using to access this page response?